# timedelta.seconds is returning a wrong value

Tags: python, django

I need to get time difference in seconds. But my function returns huge values, which I assume are microseconds. When I try to put days, I get -1 value. Can someone tell me how to get the difference in seconds.

This is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta

time_now2 = datetime.strptime(time_now, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
lt2 = datetime.strptime(LT, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
ftime = lt2 + timedelta(seconds = 1200)
waiting_time = (time_now2 - ftime).seconds
```

Comment: It's hard to understand the context of your variables if you aren't showing the full code or at least initialization of the variables that appear in your question

Comment: I agree with @dannybee.  We have no way of knowing what time_now or LT are.  Check out [this doc](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `waiting_time = (time_now2 - ftime).seconds`, could you try using `total_seconds`, instead, i.e. `(time_now2 - ftime).total_seconds()`?

Comment: Good answer.  Could be improved with a pointer to [the doc on `total_seconds`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) and maybe a description of `timedelta.seconds`.

Comment: Using totol_seconds()  gave me the right values , Thank you so much

Comment: Sure, riya fernando, great!

@rishig, thanks for the tip. ;)